# What kinds of statistical analyses and machine learning techniques are most useful for personal analytics projects?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I am just a beginner-level programmer in Python and MATLAB, and I have been looking at tutorials for Keras. Eventually, I want to make a project for my programming portfolio. Can you please share some ideas about how to get started with this project as well as any career advice about getting started with data science and machine learning?

Here's an example of a project idea I want to work towards: Machine learning applied to a series of daily logs and selfies to look for patterns of mood and activities that the user inputs as well as identify stress factors:

If implemented in a smartphone application, the program can be made to send notifications to the user when the algorithm determines it would be beneficial to the user's wellbeing. With the use of neural networks and other sources of data such as from Apple Health, more categories can be added to identify more specific moods such as anger, excitement, and sadness.

Comment: How much do you know? Are you familiar with the basics of neural networks, image recognition, app development?